# vim CTRL-] keys isn't functioning as expected

Tags: vim, ctrl

In `:help tag` it says that one can go to a tag definition using the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> keystroke. But I can't get this to work. I thought I messed some mappings with my plugins, so I cleaned `.vimrc`. But I still get cursor to a tag word (in help for example). I strike <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> simultaneously and nothing happens.

How to fix it? Or maybe I'm reading `:help` wrong?

Comment: Are you using the "English (US)" keyboard layout? Is your `]` key located just left of the Enter key? Do you have to press Shift to get a "]"?

Comment: Yes, yes and no. Thanks, at least i'm reading it right.

Comment: That's strange. Have you tried `:tag quickref` (just a random tag) or double clicking on a tag in gvim? Do these at least work?

Comment: Did you generate a `tags` file with `ctags`?

Comment: `:tag {tag_name}` is working and double click too. I fooled around with this script bundle: [link](https://github.com/akitaonrails/vimfiles), and made everything according to its `README` including `call pathogen#helptags()`. Does it changes keymapping?

Comment: For me it worked with `Ctrl` - `^`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, use the `:verbose` command (thanks to [sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562654/vim-ctrl-keys-not-working/11565329?noredirect=1#comment25918828_11565329)) to know who rebound your key where.

```
:verbose nmap <C-]>
```

Then, if you cannot find where your key was rebound, bind your<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> key by the original one then retry:

```
:nnoremap <C-]> <C-]>
```

For more info:

```
:help mapping
:help :verbose
:help :noremap
```

Comment: Don't forget: `:verbose nmap <C-]>` will tell you ***who*** rebound your key ***where***

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue, and `:verbose` did not bring up anything useful. What I figured out is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd> takes me there.

Please note that I am using a German keyboard where the plus sign sits at the position of square bracket on a US keyboard. Maybe the code only looks at the location of the key (I remember reading something to that respect in combination with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-key).

Comment: Thanks. This did the trick for me too. I am also using a German keyboard and just couldn't figure out why it's not working...

Answer (score 2):

With macOS on a Norwegian keyboard: `CTRL-]` is `CTRL-å`

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat late entry, but I had the same problem.
Thought I'd share a possible solution so others wont have to go through the agony.

The solution in my case was: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and while keeping it pressed down, press <kbd>]</kbd> twice!!! Whatever key combination you use to produce the right square bracket, <kbd>]</kbd>, do it twice!! I do not know why this works in my case. There's nothing in the help files that mentions this. Spent probably an 
hour or two trying to figure out the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> combination until I came upon the solution by accident.

Comment: This one solved my problems on console, but not on GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem on virtual box VM. The right ctrl key is to switch between the host and the guest environment. Try using left **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>** + **<kbd>]</kbd>**.

Answer (score 1):

For mee, "Ctrl-]" means "Ctrl+Alt GR+)". In other words,

- Press "Ctrl"
- Press "Alt GR" while "Ctrl" is pressed
- Press ")" ("]" is also there) while the two above are pressed

Answer (score 1):

On a Danish keybord on Windows 10 this works:

`Ctrl + ¨`

`¨` is the diuresis or umlaut sign, positioned to the right of 'å'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to default setting of Virtual box. In Oracle Virtual Box you can see by default right control is using as Host key combination. Go to File  -> Preferences-> Input and change Host key combination to "None". Initially for me also left ctrl worked and after the above changes both keys working.

Answer (score 0):

*This solution only works for linux in an X environment for non-us keyboard layouts.*

I just struggled with this problem in linux with a swiss german keyboard layout. We type ] by pressing AltGr+¨, thus i would have to use AltGr+Ctrl+¨ to jump to the ctag definition, which is awkward.

What i did was to remap the ¨ (diaeresis) key to ] (bracketright)

1. print current mapping for keycode 35:

   `$> xmodmap -pke | grep 35
   keycode  35 = dead_diaeresis exclam dead_diaeresis exclam bracketright dead_macron bracketright`
2. remap key (we just replace the first dead_diaeresis with bracketright):

   `$> xmodmap -e 'keycode 35 = bracketright exclam dead_diaeresis exclam bracketright dead_macron bracketright'`

Pressing keycode 35 (¨) will now print ] without the need of any modifier, and CTRL-] works to jump to the tag.

xmodmap -e can be executed as user without need for sudo, you can put it for example in your .profile.

see [swiss-german layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTZ#/media/File:KB_Swiss.svg) for reference

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I solved it. In my case I was maping the key CTRL + F10. So I First hit CTRL  + F10 in Vim insert mode and see what the key output is. In my case it was `F36` then I simply map it in vimrc file as

`map <F36> <CR>YOUR COMMAND<CR>`

Answer (score 0):

Same solution for a german qwertz-keyboard -> CTRL-+ did the trick! Thanks!