# gVim CTRL - ] doesn't work on Windows 7

Tags: windows, vim

CTRL-] doesn't work for me in gVim on Windows 7.
I'm new to vim so sorry if it's a noob question.

I've tried this solution: [vim CTRL-] keys not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562654/vim-ctrl-keys-not-working)

But it does nothing for me.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you try all the solutions? what is the output of `:verbose`?

Comment: Seen this? http://superuser.com/questions/195433/vim-trouble-with-ctrl-on-scandinavian-keyboards

Comment: :verbose nmap <C-]> gives No mapping found

Comment: "Doesn't work" gives almost no information. What happens when you type this key combination? Do you get an error? What did you expect to happen instead? Why did you expect that to happen?

Comment: Well, basically nothing happens. If I type ] (alt-g on my keyboard) repeatedly it just shows the ] sign on the right side of the command line and thats all.

Comment: Do you have a tags file?

Comment: Yes. I was just trying to use the :help interface where you can jump between the help file tags. But on my hungarian keyboard I just can't get CTRL-(ALT(gr))-g to jump to the file. What can be the problem?